# How to set up ssh key when pulling git repo?

Tags: git, ssh

I have things set up on my windows box and now am trying to clone a repo onto my mac machine.

If the location of a repo is

```
ssh://git@someplace/someproject.git
```

when cloning as

```
git clone ssh://git@someplace/someproject.git folder-name
```

Where (and how) do i use the SSH PPK?

The issue here is that i am not an admin of `someplace` and when prompted for a password, i don't know what it is. My SSH key however grants me access

Answer (score 3):

The following steps fixed the issue for me

In `.ssh/` create a `config` file and make sure it contains a path to your PPK

```
host someplace
user git
port 22
hostname somehost
identityfile ~/.ssh/your_key
```

Also, make sure your key's permissions are `700`

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're not using GitHub as a hosting site, their **[Set up Git](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/)** help page will be quite usefull to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use the SSH PPK in order to clone from a remote machine, the PPK just allows you to do everything without having to type a password every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to ssh to the box you are trying to clone from (the PC), so the git account on that box has to be able to ssh in using a keypair.